# How to use arg substitution in jq as a key

Tags: jq

I am trying to use an arg substitution with jq and one of the args needs to be a key.
I have tried
`$reg` - error

`"$reg"` - no sub

`\$reg` - error

Can this be done?

```
export USERNAME=joe
export PASSWORD=whatever
export DOCKER_REGISTRY="hub.docker.io"
jq -n --arg reg "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}" \
        --arg u "$USERNAME" \
        --arg p "${PASSWORD}" \
        --arg auth "$(echo "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" | base64)" \
        '{
          "auths": {
            $reg: {
              "username": $u,
              "password": $p,
              "auth": $auth
            }
          }
        }'
```

Comment: On a sidenote: Since you already `export` the values into the environment, instead of importing the values with `--arg u "$USERNAME"` and `--arg p "${PASSWORD}"` etc., and then referencing them with `{"…": $u, "…": $p}` etc., you could query the environment directly using the `env` function or the `$ENV` special variable (whichever you prefer), as in just (i.e. without any `--arg` imports) `{"…": env.USERNAME, "…": env.PASSWORD}` or `{"…": $ENV.USERNAME, "…": $ENV.PASSWORD}` etc.

Comment: AH! I didn't know I could do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

key expressions at top level need parenthesis:

This should work:

```bash
export USERNAME=joe
export PASSWORD=whatever
export DOCKER_REGISTRY="hub.docker.io"
jq -n --arg reg "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}" \
        --arg u "$USERNAME" \
        --arg p "${PASSWORD}" \
        --arg auth "$(echo "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" | base64)" \
        '{
          "auths": {
            ($reg): {
              "username": $u,
              "password": $p,
              "auth": $auth
            }
          }
        }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already exporting your variables why not use `env`?

```bash
export USERNAME=joe
export PASSWORD=whatever
export DOCKER_REGISTRY="hub.docker.io"

jq -n '{        
  "auths": {
    "\(env.DOCKER_REGISTRY)": {
      "username": env.USERNAME,    
      "password": env.PASSWORD,
      "auth": ("\(env.USERNAME):\(env.PASSWORD)"|@base64) 
    }
  }
}'
```

Output

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "hub.docker.io": {
      "username": "joe",
      "password": "whatever",
      "auth": "am9lOndoYXRldmVy"
    }
  }
}
```